# Writing a nifty mode rewrite rule need advice

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I wrote this nifty rule that changes a sub folder to a language key!
so i can have a nice clean URL and still get the language variable.
i.e.  wwww.mywebsite.com/fr/   or wwww.mywebsite.com/en/  etc...
here is the rule

```
RewriteRule ^fr/(.*)$ /$1?langId=2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^fr(.*)$ /$1?langId=2 [L,QSA]
```

it works great on its own!

but, it doesn't work when  I add it to a site with url rewrite rule like this one:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ inner.php?folder=$1 [L,QSA]
```

can anyone suggest  a rewrite rule that combines both rules?
the thing is it needs to tell the difference between one variable or two variable.
cuz sometimes i have just the folder variable, sometimes just the lang variable, and sometimes both...

it's a bit of a pickle...
10x!!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your language rules are **before** the global routing rule that routes things to the `inner.php` script.

Comment: nope... it won't do. if i put both of them the site won't load.